# selecting ALL values in PHP Dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I have dropdown list that gets values form array based on a mySQL SELECT query.  Everything is working fine except that I would like to add the option to select ALL values in the list.  Here is my code...

```
 $dataArray = array();

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, user_name FROM apsc_customers");
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $dataArray[$row['id']] = $row['user_name'];
 }
```

AND

```
 if($this->customer_id == ""){
 $this->arrFilteringFields[_CUSTOMER] = array("table"=>DB_PREFIX."customers", "field"=>"id", "type"=>"dropdownlist", "source"=>$dataArray, "sign"=>"like%", "width"=>"");
    }
```

Looking forward to any replies.

Thx

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
<select>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></option>


<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your dropdown list? I can't see it in your code. Do you mean html element select created by PHP and based on data from MySQL table? Then you need to use javascript code to select all options in such dropdown list. What is `$this` in your code? Provide more information, more code and more clarificatios.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the feedback.

yes, the dropdown list is being populates by the SELECT query.  I basically just wanted to know how to add an ALL option to the current data that is being populated.

I guess it is possible just not to select anything from the dropdown box, this way excluding that from the criteria.